# Computing Derivatives of Functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, chain-rule

In every complex analysis book I have come across (mainly Ahlfors and Stein/Shakarchi), the calculation $\frac{d}{dt} e^{it} = ie^{it}$ is taken for granted. But I want to look at this more carefully, because it doesn't seem immediately obvious to me.

The function $f(t) = e^{it}$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, and for any function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ we define the derivative by dealing with the real and imaginary parts separately: $\frac{d}{dt}(u(t) + iv(t)) := u'(t) + iv'(t)$. So working from the definition, I would compute $\frac{d}{dt}e^{it}$ by writing $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i\sin(t)$ and differentiating each component. This does give us $ie^{it}$, but what the authors of these books seem to suggest without proof is that there is a type of chain rule that can be applied to make the calculation simpler. This chain rule would have to apply to compositions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, but the only chain rules I have seen explicitly described are for compositions of differentiable functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and for holomorphic functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. In other places in the books, a chain rule for compositions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ was used, but the proof of this one is trivial in light of the definition of derivatives of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and the ordinary real chain rule. But the case $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is different from all of these, and I'm surprised none of the authors have mentioned it, as it doesn't seem to follow immediately from either the $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ chain rule.

Does such a chain rule actually exist? And if so, how do we prove it?

Comment: Isn't the $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ case just a special case of the $\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ case, especially for functions this 'nice'?

Comment: That's what I've been considering, but this seems to presume (1) that when you restrict a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, the (differently defined) derivatives match on $\mathbb{R}$; and (2) that a differentiable function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ can be extended to a holomorphic function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. I believe (1), and for this specific case (2) obviously holds, but I doubt (2) holds in general.

Comment: It follows from the multivariable chain rule if we interpret $\mathbb C$ as a 2d real vector space. It also requires the fact that the total differential (a linear map) of holomorphic functions is just multiplication by their complex derivative (also a linear map).

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Does it really? The notion of complex differentiation of functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is different from the total derivative of a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and to my knowledge knowing the Jacobian of $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ at a point $z_0$ isn't enough to compute $f'(z_0)$.

Comment: The notion of complex differentiability is *stronger* than that of total differentiability. Holomorphic functions are automatically totally differentiable.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos But isn't that the exact reason why we can't rely on the (weaker) notion of total differentiability to prove this result about holomorphic functions?

Comment: If the multivariable chain rule holds for totally differentiable functions, it also holds for holomorphic functions, because those, too, are totally differentiable. But in addition, holomorphy tells us about how the total differential of a holomorphic function behaves: $\mathrm Df_{z_0}(h)=f'(z_0)\cdot h$, where $h$ is a complex number.

Comment: (1) absolutely holds true; if the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)-f(x_0))/(x-x_0)$ exists in $\mathbb{C}$ then every sequence of points $x$ converging to $x_0$ yields the same limit; in particular, the sequences where all $x$ are real do. (2) is why I mentioned the niceness of the function; if you want a chain rule for functions $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ that are real differentiable but not holomorphic then I think things become less clear, but that's moot for 99% of functions that are likely to show up in an analysis text and it's certainly moot here.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Makes perfect sense, I'm satisfied with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Expanding out my comments into an answer)

First of all, I'm not sure that I agree with your definition of the complex derivative via $\frac{d}{dt}\left(u(t)+iv(t)\right)=\frac{du(t)}{dt}+i\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$. While that's true, I see it as a consequence of the canonical definition of the derivative of a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to any vector space $V$ over it, $\frac{d}{dt}f(t)|_{t_0}$ $= \lim\limits_{t\to t_0}\dfrac{f(t)-f(t_0)}{t-t_0}$. I feel like this definition is better both because it's more 'holistic' (there's no breaking the function into real and imaginary parts) and more general (it applies over more than just $\mathbb{C}$). The rule $(u+iv)'=u'+iv'$ then becomes a handy computational shortcut that falls out readily from this definition.

In the particular case $V=\mathbb{C}$, since $\mathbb{R}$ sits inside $\mathbb{C}$, we can say a lot more: the functions from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ are a subset of the functions for $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, and in fact every sufficiently 'nice' function (specifically, every analytic function) $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ extends to a nice-enough function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. (I'm being a little bit loose here; in particular, the function may have singularities and so not necessarily be defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$, e.g. $f(t)=\frac{1}{t^2+1}$. But it will be well-defined on an open set containing the real line.) In particular, the derivative of a function $f$ viewed as an analytic function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ can be seen as the derivative of $f$ viewed as an analytic function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, which is then restricted to $\mathbb{R}$. These derivatives are guaranteed to coincide, because the limit in the definition of derivative must agree over any sequence converging to $t_0$, and in particular will agree on all the sequences $t\to t_0$ where all the $t$ are in $\mathbb{R}$. So by and large, you can really view the $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ case as a special case of $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. If you're interested in non-analytic $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ then certainly things are going to get a little more complicated, but I'd say that the huge majority of functions you hit in low-level analysis texts are going to be analytic.